# how can i open auto datepicker range departure

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

sorry my question maybe is too esay but i am not understand javascript. i have a range datepicker. arrival-departure. i want to when i selected arrival auto open departure picker. here is my js code.

```
$('#arrival').datetimepicker({
                        useCurrent: false,
                        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                        minDate: 'now'
                    });
        $('#departure').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false,
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            minDate: 'now'
        });
        $("#arrival").on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {
            $('#departure').datetimepicker('minDate', e.date);
        });
        $("#departure").on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {
            $('#arrival').datetimepicker('maxDate', e.date);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [onShow()](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#onShow) callback with `setOptions()` to set the min and max dates on the datetimepicker on the fly.

A few other things I noticed:

`e.date` is undefined so I used the `.val()` of the date time picker for the dates.

Also your format was off you are doubling month names and days and quadrupling years. So I set it to format 04/May/2018 format in the below example.

I also set the max date on the arrival picker (to the departure time) if the departure is set, otherwise there is now max.

```js
$('#arrival').datetimepicker({
  useCurrent: false,
  format: 'd/M/Y',
  onShow: function(ct) {
    this.setOptions({
      minDate: "now",
      maxDate: $('#departure').val() ? new Date($('#departure').val()) : false
    })
  }
});

$('#departure').datetimepicker({
  useCurrent: false,
  format: 'd/M/Y',
  onShow: function(ct) {
    this.setOptions({
      minDate: new Date($('#arrival').val())
    })
  }
});

$("#arrival").on("change.datetimepicker", function(e) {
  $('#departure').datetimepicker("show");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

arrive <input id="arrival" type="text"> 
depart <input id="departure" type="text">
```

Comment: perfect. thank you so much. and last question. when i select departure how can i clouse datepicker auto. i mean i select arrival ->open departure i select departure date close datepicker

Comment: i try its clouse auto everything is okay. thank you so much